# Get response after sharing in LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am using this code to share on linkedin.

```
IN.UI.Share().params({
  url: "http://www.example.com"
}).place();
```

It's working perfect, but I need to get response after sharing the post.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Successful Share callback? | LinkedIn Developer Network](https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2368)

Comment: i don't want use this method

Comment: <script type="IN/Share" data-url="[URL]" data-onSuccess="[successCallback]" data-onError="[errorCallback]"></script>However, result is still the same: share is executed ok, callback is not.
 can i call callback function in IN.UI.Share().params({
url: "http://www.example.com"
}).place();

Comment: From what I see this has no relation to PHP, tags should be Javascript and LinkedIn

Answer (score 1):

you may want to simply do an AJAX query to the REST api.  you'll get back a 201 response with some XML data.  Per [their website](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api):

**Response**

Returns 201 Created on success. Upon success, the body of the response will contain the following:

```
<update>
  <update-key>UNIU-8219502-5705061301949063168-SHARE</update-key>
  <update-url>http://www.linkedin.com/updates?discuss=&amp;scope=8219502&amp;stype=M&amp;topic=5705061301949063168&amp;type=U&amp;a=aovi</update-url>
</update>
```

You can use the **update key** to request the XML or JSON representation of the newly created share. This can be achieved by making a GET call to `http://www.linkedin-ei.com/v1/people/~/network/updates/key={update_key}` (setting `{update_key}` to the value you received in the previous response)